# Add active class to button when start typing in input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code and I want to add the active class to the (withdraw-btn) button when I start typing in input and remove it again if I removed the text that I entered in input (when input is empty).

The code is running fine, but the problem is: that the active class is not added when I start typing in input so I must click outside that input.

I want to add an active class just start typing and remove it just delete the text in the input.

** Sorry For the bad language

HTML

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
      <div class="withdrawal-amount">
         <p>Withdrawal Amount (Minimum required: $10)</p>
         <input type="text" placeholder="$10" class="withdrawal-amount-input">
      </div>
   </div> 
   <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="withdraw-btn-upper">
         <a href="#" class="withdraw-btn">Withdraw</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function addActiveclass() {
    $(".withdrawal-amount-input").on("change", function(){
        if($(this).val() == "")
            $(".withdraw-btn").removeClass('active');
        else
            $(".withdraw-btn").addClass('active');
    });
    
}
addActiveclass();
```

Answer (score 3):

Listen for the `input` event instead:

```js
function addActiveclass() {
    $(".withdrawal-amount-input").on("input", function(){
        if($(this).val() == "")
            $(".withdraw-btn").removeClass('active');
        else
            $(".withdraw-btn").addClass('active');
    });
    
}
addActiveclass();
```

```css
.active{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
      <div class="withdrawal-amount">
         <p>Withdrawal Amount (Minimum required: $10)</p>
         <input type="text" placeholder="$10" class="withdrawal-amount-input">
      </div>
   </div> 
   <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="withdraw-btn-upper">
         <a href="#" class="withdraw-btn">Withdraw</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```